# How do I stop an MDI child form being dragged outside the edges of the parent?

Tags: c#

[image]

"People" is a MDI parent Form
"New" is MDI child Form

How can I stop "New" From being dragged outside "People" edges?

I found that code its working good

```
    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // Get the MDI Client window reference
        //
        MdiClient mdiClient = null;
        foreach (Control ctl in MdiParent.Controls)
        {
            mdiClient = ctl as MdiClient;
            if (mdiClient != null)
                break;
        }
        //
        // Don't allow moving form outside of MDI client bounds
        //
        if (Left < mdiClient.ClientRectangle.Left)
            Left = mdiClient.ClientRectangle.Left;
        if (Top < mdiClient.ClientRectangle.Top)
            Top = mdiClient.ClientRectangle.Top;
        if (Top + Height > mdiClient.ClientRectangle.Height)
            Top = mdiClient.ClientRectangle.Height - Height;
        if (Left + Width > mdiClient.ClientRectangle.Width)
            Left = mdiClient.ClientRectangle.Width - Width;
        base.OnMove(e);
    }
```

Comment: Prevent it from *appearing* there, or from being *dragged* there?

Comment: I dont want it to be dragged to the edges

Comment: Consider updating your question with these kinds of tidbits of information. =)

Comment: You cannot drag MDI child windows beyond the parent's edge, no matter how hard you try.  Surely you are talking about something else, the answer is "don't use MDI if you don't like the MDI windowing model".  Lots of docked-window class libraries around.

Comment: @Hans: As i'm understanding it at this point, the question isn't how to move child frames outside the parent; it's apparently rather the opposite.  I'm getting "how do i keep child frames *entirely* within the parent's visible area?"  (ie: how to keep the child frame from being dragged to a spot where the parent's edge cuts it off)

Answer (score 0):

The MDI parent form relocates new form kind of like displaying multiple forms cascading. To relocate the window you have to set the location in the `Form_Loading` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

set the child forms StartPosition to CenterParent

Answer (score 0):

Hide mdi container's scroll bars , sample code :

```
internal sealed class NonScrollableWindow : NativeWindow
{
    private readonly MdiClient _mdiClient;

    public NonScrollableWindow(MdiClient parent)
    {
        _mdiClient = parent;
        ReleaseHandle();
        AssignHandle(_mdiClient.Handle);
    }
    internal void OnHandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseHandle();
    }
    private const int SB_BOTH = 3;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, int bShow);
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        ShowScrollBar(m.HWnd, SB_BOTH, 0);
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Usage (in mdi parent load event),

```
 foreach (MdiClient control in Controls.OfType<MdiClient>())
        {
            if (control != null)
            {
                new NonScrollableWindow(control);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the move event of the child you can use code to detect if the current position is beyond where you want it to be. You'll need to have previously established the parent window's top, left, bottom and right edges.

code like:

```
BufferWidth = 10; // 10 pixel buffer to edge
// ParentTop is the top Y co-ordinate of the parent window

if (this.location.Y > (ParentTop-BufferWidth))
{
    int LocX = this.Location.X;
    this.location = new Point(LocX, (ParentTop-BufferWidth));
}
```

You would need to repeat this for each of the sides. Code can be more streamlined by calculating the edges with buffer in advance as they will only change when the parent window moves.